# Search Todays date in column and select cell

Tags: vba, excel, date

I found a code but I don't why it is not working, I'm barely new to VBA. Please help me..

What I am trying to achieve is I need to Search the day today from another wb.

Here's my complete code:

```
    Sub Sample

Sheets("Database").Select
Dim i as Workbook
Dim c as Workbook

Set i = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsm")
Set c = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Range("U2").Value)
'U2 contains the link or path of the file.

ThisWorkbook.Activate

Sheets("Summary").Activate
Windows("Workbook1").Activate
Sheets("Database").Select

Workbooks(2).Activate
Sheets("Summary").Select

Dim FindString As Date
Dim Rng As Range

FindString = CLng(Date)
With Sheets("Summary").Range("A:A")
Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlbyColumns, SearchDirection;=xlNext,MatchCase;=False)

If Not Rng Is nothing then
Application.Goto Rng, True
Else
Msgbox "Nothing Then"
End if
End with
End Sub
```

The other workbook that was recently opened contains Summary Sheet that has Dates on Column A:A

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro that works? That would be a start. Hard to know with shoiwng example data in your cells. There are two possibilities that I see - `After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count),` -looks like it's looking at all the blank cells after your first one - that doesn't make sense to me.  Also possible that `LookIn:=xlFormulas` should maybe be looking at `xlValues`?,

Comment: What are trying to do if you find the date in the other wb?

Comment: select the cell that contains the date.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a syntax error - the two parameters are defined with semi-colons ";" instead of colons ":"

`SearchDirection;=xlNext,MatchCase;=False`

becomes

`SearchDirection:=xlNext,MatchCase:=False`

Fix your syntax before testing - Use Debug | Compile

Answer (score 0):

Activating and Selecting is not necessary and harmful

There are also some syntax errors

You may want to re-start from the following code:

```
Sub Sample
    Dim dbSheet as Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set dbSheet = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsm").Sheets("Database") 'set the “database” worksheet
    With Workbooks.Open(FileName:=dbSheet.Range("U2").Value).Sheets("Summary") 'open the workbook whose link is in “database” sheet cell U2 and reference its “Summary” sheet
        With  .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) ' reference referenced sheet column A cells from row 1 down to last not empty row
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=CLng(Date), After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False) ' try finding current date starting from the cell at the top of referenced range
        End With 
    End With 
    If Not Rng Is nothing then
        Application.Goto Rng, True
    Else
        Msgbox "Nothing Then"
    End if
End Sub
```

This code is untested but from the explanations in comments you can tweak it to reach the goal

Comment: Thanks Mate! I'll try it out and I'll go back to if this does work!

Comment: you are welcome. just found out some syntax error myself! see editecode

Comment: I did not encountered any error though it did not select the cell that contains the date today. Cell that contains the date is a formula. I did change the LookIn:=xlValues to xlFormulas yet nothing happened.